# Why isn't the Nelson-Siegel model arbitrage-free?

Tags: interest-rates, models, arbitrage, yield-curve

Assume $X_t$ is a multivariate Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, i.e.
$$dX_t=\sigma dB_t-AX_tdt$$
and the spot interest rate evolves by the following equation:
$$r_t=a+b\cdot X_t.$$
After solving for $X_t$ using $e^{tA}X_t$ and Ito and looking at $\int_0^T{r_s\;ds}$, it turns out that 
$$\int_0^T{r_s\;ds} \sim \mathcal{N}(aT+b^{T}(I-e^{-TA})A^{-1}X_0,b^{T}V_Tb)$$
where $V_t$ is the covariance matrix of $\int_0^T(I-e^{-(T-u)A})A^{-1}\sigma dB_u$.

This gives us the yield curve
$$y(t)=a+\frac{b^{T}(I-e^{-tA})A^{-1}X_0}{t}+\frac{b^{T}V_tb}{2t}$$
and by plugging in $A= 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \lambda & 1  \\
  0 & \lambda  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$
we finally arrive at
$$y(t)=a+\frac{1-e^{-\lambda t}}{\lambda t}C_0+e^{-\lambda t}C_1+\frac{b^{T}V_tb}{2t}.$$
The formula above without $\frac{b^{T}V_tb}{2t}$ is known as the Nelson-Siegel yield curve model. Could somebody clarify why neglecting $\frac{b^{T}V_tb}{2t}$ leads to arbitrage opportunities?

So I am essentially asking the following question:

Why is the above model (with $\frac{b^{T}V_tb}{2t}$) arbitrage free?

Comment: Where did you get this derivation of the NS model? I'm only familiar with Filipovic (1999) (http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-9965.00073/abstract) showing that arbitrage is possible in the standard NS formulation and the solution of Christensen et al. (2009) (http://www.frbsf.org/publications/economics/papers/2007/wp07-20bk.pdf) who add a yield adjustment term.

Comment: This derivation was given by Chris Rogers, who is teaching Advanced Financial Models at the University of Cambridge this year. Here's a scan of the notes, taken by a student of his class: http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~chris/AFM/AFM_L21.pdf

Answer (score 8):

The original [Nelson Siegel paper](http://www.math.ku.dk/~rolf/teaching/NelsonSiegel.pdf) describes a parsimonious model of the term structure using only four or three (if $\lambda_t$ is fixed). [Filipovic (1999)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-9965.00073/abstract) proves that this model can never be used in a arbitrage free context, paraphrasing the abstract:

> We introduce the class of *consistent state space processes*, which
>     have the property to provide an arbitrage-free interest rate model
>     when representing the parameters of the Nelson–Siegel (NS)
>     family. (We show that) there exists no nontrivial interest rate
>     model driven by a consistent state space Itō process.

This problem is solved by [Christensen et al. (2009)](http://www.frbsf.org/publications/economics/papers/2007/wp07-20bk.pdf). They provide some ODE's which must hold for an AFNS and write that the "key difference between Dynamic NS and AFNS is the maturity dependent *yield-adjustment* term" and show how to solve for this term.

They show that the yield adjustment term is empirically small and that their model

> fares well in out-of-sample prediction, consistently outperforming, for example, the canonical $A_0(3)$ model (of [Duffee 2002](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.194.7118&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).

Answer (score 4):

Let $P(t,T)$ be the time-$t$ price of the zero-coupon bond expiring at $T$.

The no-arbitrage condition forces:
$$e^{-\int_0^tr_sds}P(t,T)=\mathbb{E}[e^{-\int_0^Tr_sds}|\mathcal{F_t}],$$ where $\mathcal{F_t}$ is the filtration of the Brownian motion up to time $t$. Note that the expression on the right is a martingale by the tower property of expectations, so by the First Theorem of Asset pricing, there is no arbitrage.
It immediately follows that
$$P(t,T)=\mathbb{E}[e^{-\int_t^Tr_sds}],$$
which will further result in the yield curve specified as above (with $V_t$ term). Therefore neglecting the covariance term *could* result in arbitrage.

In fact, I was told that there is a proof showing it is not indeed arbitrage-free, but I am not going to go into that.